# Tab bar items not showing up until clicked

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to create a tab bar controller with a navigation controller. I am trying to achieve this programmatically.

Here's the willConnectTo method in my Scene delegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    
    // Create the tab bar controller
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    
    let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MoviesScreen())
    let vc2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: FavouritesScreen())
    
    vc1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "film")
    vc1.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(systemName: "film.fill")
    
    vc2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(systemName: "heart")
    vc2.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")
    
    tabBarController.setViewControllers([vc1, vc2], animated: false)
    
    window.rootViewController = tabBarController
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

And here are the 2 view controllers:

```
class MoviesScreen: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        title = "Movies"
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

}

class FavouritesScreen: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        title = "Favourites"
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
}
```

The screenshot below shows what the app looks like when I run it:
[image: Image 1]

But when I click on the tab bar item, the item shows up:
[image: Image 2]

As you can see in the first screenshot, the second tab bar item is not visible. I tried the existing fixes I could find on the internet but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue, all I had to do was just add a tint color to the tab bar like so:

```
tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(named: "themeColor") // Custom color
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently as well. It seems to be a initialization/lifecycle specific thing.

You're supposed to set `tabBarItem` on each view controller, and I found that if I set `tabBarItem` in the `viewDidLoad` function - which most of us are accustomed to doing, the tab bar item would not be rendered until clicked on.

Moving the `tabBarItem` assignment up to init (which requires creating the init overrides for the ViewController), resolved the problem, and it now appears immediately as expected.

```
    public override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Debug", image: UIImage(systemName: "ant.circle"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "ant.circle.fill"))
        self.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
        self.title = "Debug"
    }
```

Comment: your method is what I ended up using to solve the same problem in XCode 14.2, Swift 5. Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

When working with storyboards, the tab bar items are set in 'init?(coder: NSCoder)'. If you would like to set it in code, there are two possibilities:

1. Set the tab bar item in the init method of the view controller
2. Configure the tab bar item
   on a given view controller but do it before presenting it in the
   TabBarController.

Example 1:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    tabBarItem = .init(title: "title", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
}
```

Example 2:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.tabBarItem = .init(title: "title", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
let tbc = UITabBarController()
tbc.viewControllers = [vc]
```